# Moq + Unit Testing + System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter Count mismatch

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am getting a "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter Count mismatch" exception when attempting to mock our ApiClient.

I am using the following code to Setup the Moq response

```
private void SetupApiClientForGetZones(IEnumerable<Zone> zone)
{
    this.MockHubApiClient.Setup(x => x.GetAsync<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()))
                .Returns(
                    (string name) =>
                    {
                        return zone == null ? Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Zone>>(null) : Task.Run(() => zone);
                    });

            this.MockApiClientFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(this.MockHubApiClient.Object);
        }
```

The iApiClient interface I attempting to Mock is

```
public interface IApiClientAsync : IApiClient
    {
        Task<string> GetAsync(string apiController);

        Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string apiController) where T : class;

        Task<string> GetAsync(string apiController, IDictionary<string, string> param, string queryString);

        Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string apiController, IDictionary<string, string> param) where T : class;
}
```

My unit test is

```
[Test]
public void GetZonesNotCached()
{
    var data = new List<Zone> { new Zone { ZoneId = 1, ZoneName = "Test Zone 1" }, new Zone { ZoneId = 2, ZoneName = "Test Zone 2" } };

    this.SetupApiClientForGetZones(data);

    this.MockCache.Setup(x => x.GetItemFromCache<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>()));

    var organisationService = new OrganisationService(this.MockUnitOfWorkAsync.Object, this.MockApiClientFactory.Object, this.MockCache.Object);

    var results = organisationService.GetZones(1, 1).ToList();

    Assert.IsNotNull(results);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, results.Count, "There should be 3 records returned");

    this.MockCache.Verify(x => x.GetItemFromCache<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
    this.MockHubApiClient.Verify(x => x.GetAsync<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()), Times.Once());
}
```

I have found numerous other posts with the same exception but none of the solutions or examples are the same as mine.

I have been able to successfully Mock the response when calling the GetAsync method that only has the single string paramter.

```
    private void SetupApiClientForAllDealerDetails(IEnumerable<DealerDetail> dealerDetails)
    {
        this.MockHubApiClient.Setup(
            x => x.GetAsync<IEnumerable<DealerDetail>>(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(
                (string name) =>
                {
                    return dealerDetails == null ? Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<DealerDetail>>(null) : Task.Run(() => dealerDetails);
                });

        this.MockApiClientFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(this.MockHubApiClient.Object);
    }
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an expression in your .Returns instead of a value, then that expression's parameters must match those of the method signature you are mocking.

For example, I found this in *SetupApiClientForGetZones*:

```
this.MockHubApiClient.Setup(x => x.GetAsync<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()))
                .Returns(
                    (string name) =>
                      {
                        return zone == null ? Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Zone>>(null) : Task.Run(() => zone);
                      });
```

When really it should be:

```
this.MockHubApiClient.Setup(x => x.GetAsync<IEnumerable<Zone>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()))
                .Returns<string, IDictionary<string, string>>(
                    (name, dict) =>
                      {
                        return zone == null ? Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Zone>>(null) : Task.Run(() => zone);
                      });
```